When to substitute the point when working with vectors
I'm getting confused at this:
If i'm trying to find the first normal of this expression r(t)=(t^2,t^3+3t,0) at t=1, can i just first find the tangent and then use t=1, and differentiate again from there? Or do i have to keep working with vectors until i've reached the parametric expression for the first normal and then use t=1 from there?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

It's hard to really understand what is the first method. If you find the first tangent, set $t=1$ you will have a constant expression. When you differentiate that you get $0$)
